# What materials that can contain water and ultrasound wave can go through

Tags: waves, material-science

Currently, I'm studying about Ultrasound wave. My aim is set up a system that ultrasound wave can go through ( not reflect and not absorb ultrasound wave). Besides that, this material can contain liquid. Can you give me what materials can adapt this experiment? Best regards.

Comment: Is a womb too obvious  ?